# Why would this be a contradiction?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n\ge 3$ be odd. Let $x\in D_{2n}$. If $x=r^a$ where $0<a<n$ let $q\ge 2$.

So $2a<2n\le qn$.

I was reading a proof stating that the only commuting element of $D_{2n}$ is the identity when $n$ is odd and this was stated as a contradiction, but I don't understand why.

Comment: It isn't.  Your conditions on $a,n,q$ make both inequalities true.

Comment: That's what I had thought